# Calling BaseProduct.getBatteries() returns list of 6 batteries for Mavik Pro

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I am using the Android DJI Mobile SDK for an android app.  I'm making the app usable for any DJI Aircraft.

After I've connected to the Mavik Pro, I call BaseProduct.getBatteries() and this returns me a list of 6 batteries.  However, the Mavik only has one battery, so I'm wondering if its a bug that this method returns me 6 batteries rather than 1

Or is there something I'm not understanding correctly?

(Note: If I connect to the Matrice 600, then I also get back 6 batteries which is expected b/c it has 6 batteries. I have only tested the app with these two aircrafts)

Answer (score 1):

For Mavic, that should return an array of size 1.
So the behavior you are describing is not expected.
Are you using the latest SDK (4.3.2 at the moment)?
If not which version are you using?

Comment: I'm not working on this project anymore; however, I know I was using the latest version at 8/25/17